# Why is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module a finitely generated $\mathcal O_K$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

There is something I don't understand in Neukirch's Algebraic number theorey. He said that:

"every ideal is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module by (2.10) and therefore a fortiori a finitely generated $\mathcal O_K$-module."

I know that every ideal is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module but I fail to understand why then it is a finitely generated $\mathcal O_K$-module.
Could someone tell me something? Appreciate that.

Comment: Because  an $\mathcal O_K$-module is also a $\mathbf Z$-module (by restriction of scalars), and ‘he who can do the more can do the less’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $R \subset S$ are rings and $M$ is an $S$-module which is finitely generated as an $R$-module, then it is finitely generated as an $S$-module too. Indeed, if $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ is a list of generators, then everything in $M$ is a finite $R$-linear combination $\sum r_i m_i$, so it's also a finite $S$-linear combination because the coefficients $r_i$ are also in $S$.

Comment: (not needed for your particular question, but this generalizes to the case that $f: R \to S$ is some not necessarily injective map and we view $M$ as an $R$-module via $f$.)

Comment: yeah……seems that I asked a dumb question, thanks anyway.